Preserve indentation when wrapping lines in a table column
I would like to preserve the horizontal space on the left-hand side of the 1st column when a newline occurs automatically.
Thank you.
MWE :
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[table, svgnames]{xcolor}

\colorlet{maincolor}{ForestGreen}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}%
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.4}%
\rowcolors{1}{}{maincolor!20}%
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{1pt}% 
\arrayrulecolor{maincolor}%
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{%
>{\raggedright\arraybackslash\hspace*{20pt}\hsize=1.7\hsize}X|%
>{\Centering\hsize=0.3\hsize}X%
}%
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{Produit} & Coefficient \\
\hline
Crédit de trésorerie confirmé non utilisé (durée $\leq$ 1 an) & 0.2 \\
Credit de trésorerie confirmé non utilisé (durée $>$ 1 an) & 0.5 \\
Crédit documentaire non gagé sur la marchandise & 0.5 \\
Crédit documentaire garantie par les marchandises & 0.2 \\
Garantie financière d'achèvement, garantie de bonne fin et garantie de restitution d'acompte & 0.2
\end{tabularx}%
\end{table}

\end{document}




You could remove the \hspace*{20pt} and (if desired) use @{\hspace{20pt)\hspace{\tabcolsep}} before the first column.

I suggest you change
\hspace*{20pt}

to
\hangafter=0\hangindent=20pt

That way, the indentation is applied to all lines.
Separately, I'd use just one X-type column, and use the c column type for the second column. That way, you don't have to fiddle with the \hsize stuff.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{iftex}
\ifpdftex
  %%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % that's the default nowadays
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}      % new
\fi

\usepackage[french]{babel} % new
%%\usepackage{multicol}    % are you sure you need this package?
\usepackage{multirow}
%%\usepackage{array}       % is loaded automatically by 'tabularx'
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{ragged2e}      % for '\RaggedRight' macro

\usepackage[table, svgnames]{xcolor}
\colorlet{maincolor}{ForestGreen}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
%\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt} % don't use this unless you really know what you're doing
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.4}
\rowcolors{1}{}{maincolor!20}
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{1pt} 
\arrayrulecolor{maincolor}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{%
  >{\RaggedRight\hangafter=0\hangindent=20pt}X | c }

\multicolumn{1}{c|}{Produit} & Coefficient \\
\hline
Crédit de trésorerie confirmé non utilisé (durée $\leq$ 1 an) & 0.2 \\
Credit de trésorerie confirmé non utilisé (durée $>$ 1 an) & 0.5 \\
Crédit documentaire non gagé sur la marchandise & 0.5 \\
Crédit documentaire garantie par les marchandises & 0.2 \\
Garantie financière d'achèvement, garantie de bonne fin et garantie de restitution d'acompte & 0.2
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}

